# How to get reference objects in many-to-many relationship in Realm (Kotlin SDK)?

Tags: kotlin, realm, kotlin-multiplatform, realm-mobile-platform

I'm trying to implement a many-to-many relationship between Record and Tag objects. Each Record can have multiple tags.

```kotlin
open class Record : RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String = ""
    var title: String = ""
    var description: String = ""

    var tags: RealmList<Tag> = realmListOf()
}

open class Tag : RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String = ""
    var name: String = ""

    val record: RealmResults<Record> by backlinks(Record::tags)
}
```

When testing the saving of Record objects, I noticed the following issue. In the case where we save a Record with a Tag that doesn't exist in the Tags table, that tag is automatically added. However, if we try to save a Record with a tag that already exists in the Tags table, we get the following exception - "**Attempting to create an object of type 'Tag' with an existing primary key value '1'**".

I write a Record object with a list of Tags as follows:

```kotlin
val record = Record().apply {
    id = randomUUID()
    title = "TestRecord"
    description = "Desc"
    tags = realmListOf(
        Tag().apply {
            id = "1"
            name = "Tag1"
        },
        Tag().apply {
            id = "2"
            name = "Tag2"
        }
    )
}
realm.write {
    copyToRealm(record)
}
```

Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The code looks great! Theres a forward relationship and also inverse; that will allow the object graph to be transversed in both directions. As mentioned in the question, to find a certain Record, a query could be run against Records where tags contains a certain Tag; there's nothing wrong with that. See [Read Objects](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/kotlin/realm-database/crud/read/#read-realm-objects---kotlin-sdk). But... since Tags contain backlinks to their Record objects, that's probably an easier way to go; read in the Tag and the records property and you have all of it's Records.

Comment: @Jay Thank you for the answer.
I have come to a different decision. It seems that we need a third table anyway to implement a many-to-many relationship. Now I have three objects: Record, Tag and RecordTagRef(id, recordId, tagId). It's also worth noting that Realm automatically inserts objects specified in a RealmList (specifically objects, not scalars). Now I simply get all recordIds from the RecordTagRef table for the desired tagId.

Comment: you do not need a third table to implement many-to-many relationships; that's a built in feature of Realm. It handles but forward relationships with List and reverse with backlinks. Both of those are 'to-many' style properties. You're use case may vary but it is something built-in.

Comment: @Jay I don't quite understand how to implement this exactly. The thing is, every time we save a Record object with a list of Tags (in the 'tags' property), these tags will automatically be added to the Tag table. In other words, the tags will be duplicated. I need the Tag table to contain unique Tags, but at the same time, I should be able to retrieve all records that contain a specific tag. Please help me figure this out.

Comment: When a tag is added to a record object within a write, it would *only* be created if it didn't already exist and then a reference to that object is added to the List. If it exists, only a reference to that object is added to the List. Objects will never be duplicated unless it's specifically coded that way - which may be the case here. There's no code in the question which duplicates the issue. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Update the question and we'll take a look.

Comment: @Jay I've just checked that when we insert a new record containing a new tag (which does not exist in the Tags table), the new tag is simply added. However, if there is already a tag with the same primary key in the Tags table, we get an exception when trying to save the record - Attempting to create an object of type 'Tag' with an existing primary key value '1'. I've updated the question.

Comment: The error being described is what it should be. See the [Realm Docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/kotlin/realm-database/schemas/property-annotations/#specify-a-primary-key) which states **Primary key values must be unique across all instances of an object in a realm. Attempting to insert a duplicate primary key value results in an error**. Your code is attempting to create an object that already exists (at least the primary key does) - hence the error. I am not clear on the use case but if you want to add an existing Tag to a Record, that's not how to do it.

Comment: See [RealmList](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/kotlin/latest/library-base/io.realm.kotlin.types/-realm-list/index.html) docs on how to add objects - either new or existing to a RealmList.

Comment: @Jay I need the behavior that you described in the previous comment: "If it exists, only a reference to that object is added to the List".
If I remove the primary key annotation for the Tag object, then the entries in the Tags table will be duplicated.
How can we make sure that when we save a Record with an already existing tag (in the Tags table), this Record is saved without an exception and the tag is not duplicated? The documentation doesn't seem to say anything about this.

Comment: Reading an existing managed Tag from Realm **first** will then allow it to be added to a Record without duplicating. If you create a new Tag with the same primary key as one that's already managed, you'll get the error, which is what you're seeing in your code. The code that's missing is reading in the Tag you want to add first. Likewise, if you know the primary key of the object you want to modify, you can [Upsert an object](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/kotlin/realm-database/crud/update/#upsert-a-realm-object) which either adds a new object or modifies and existing one.

Comment: @Jay Now, after adding 'UpdatePolicy.ALL' when writing Record objects, the tags that already exist are not added, and the Record is saved without any issues.
Thank you so much! You're the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue here is the understanding of how Realm objects interact; unmanaged vs managed

Let me address this at a high level with some pseudo code

Suppose theres a Record and Tag objects and nothing yet exists in your Realm database. Record has a RealmList of Tags

Create a Tag and add it to a Record.

```
var t0 = Tag(withPrimaryKey: 0)
var myRecord = Record()
myRecord.myTags.add(t0)
realm.add(myRecord) //success since it doesn't exist
```

This will succeed and both a tag and record will be added to Realm! But then later we do this

```
let myRecord = read a record from Realm
var t0 = Tag(withPrimaryKey: 0)
myRecord.myTags.add(t0) //fail as this primary key exists
```

The above will fail because the Tag with primary key 0 already exists, and primary keys must be unique

However, assume the Realm database has only one entry, a Tag with primary key of 0

```
let t0 = read Tag with primary key 0 from realm
let myRecord = Record()
myRecord.myTags.add(t0)
realm.add(myRecord) //success since t0 was already managed
```

will succeed and the Tag with primary key 0 will NOT be duplicated. Since it was already a managed object (e.g. stored in realm), it's simply added to the myRecord, myTags property as a reference to the  managed object.

If you know a specific objects primary key, you can also [Upsert](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/kotlin/realm-database/crud/update/#upsert-a-realm-object) it; that process will either create the object if it doesn't exist, or modify the object if it does.